# Chrome extension response TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, undefined

I got response data from var hello in background.js but
in console I got for this line "request.greeting.text === "varhello"" this error:

*Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
at chrome-extension://jmekelgdokcelbkancdgfgagmiopdlpl/background.js:53:30*

Content.js :

```
var varHello = {
    image_url: 'www.google.com',
    text: "varhello"
};
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    {greeting: varHello}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
});
```

Background.js :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(sender.tab ?
            "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
            "from the extension");

        if (request.greeting.text === "varhello"){
            sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
            console.log(request.greeting);
        }
        //console.log(request.greeting.toString());
    });
```

Wait for your solution to have clean console :-) tnx!

Comment: It means there's some code that's sending a different object. But if the code in the question is all you have then it sounds like you're looking at an old error in chrome://extensions page. It doesn't clear the list of errors when you reload the extension so you need to do it manually - there's a button for that.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like at some point in time request.greeting is undefined. Use ?. operator, watch [ES2020](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/new-javascript-features-in-es2020-c2d76acf9c5a) for more info, like this: `request.greeting?.text` of `if (request.greeting && request.greeting.text === "varhello")`

Comment: Downvoting since you're suggesting a workaround without even trying to investigate and fix the real problem - the wrong object being received.

Comment: thanks for your answer if you mean use :                                                     (request.greeting && request.greeting.text === "varhello")                                                          I tried that but still same as previous the API works but undefined is still there.